# Actualizar una columna de una tabla sin actualizar la página completa

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo una tabla que muestra registros de la base de datos con un `while`. Esos registros contienen un peso en gramos que debe ser calculado en función del precio actual de una materia prima. Obtengo ese precio de la materia prima a través de JSON haciendo un setinterval() cada cierto tiempo en un fichero.

Lo que hago es calcular cada minuto el precio del gramo, pero lo que quiero es que se actualice en tiempo real y solamente el campo de la tabla que muestra el precio `<span id='total_precio_peso'></span>`.

El problema es que solo me actualiza el precio del primer registro y no de todos. Para recoger esa variable utilizo este script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.post("var1.php", function(data){
          if(data.length >0) {
              var recoge=data.split("-");                        
              $('nombre').html(recoge[0]); 
              $('.total_precio_peso').html(recoge[1]);                                     
          }   
        });
        }, 10000, true);
    });
</script>

<?php 
$sql_o=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM monedas WHERE id_user = $user_id");

                while ($row_o=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_o)){
                    $nombre=$row_o['nombre'];
                    $peso=$row_o['gramos'];
                    ?>                 
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <? echo $nombre; ?>
                           </td>
                          <td>
                            <? echo $peso; ?>
                          </td>
                          <td><span class='total_precio_peso'></span></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

En el fichero **var1.php** es el fichero que se actualiza cada minuto (por ejemplo) para obtener el precio en ese momento por JSON y luego hacer la operación por gramo que quiero mostrar en la tabla de arriba, lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<?php 
    //$precio_obtenido es la variable donde obtengo el precio con JSON en este mismo fichero. No pongo esas llamadas porque funcionan correctamente.
    $sql_o=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM monedas WHERE id_user = $user_id");

        while ($row_o=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_o)){
            $gramos=$row_o['gramos'];

            $total = $precio_obtenido * $gramos;         
            echo "-".$total; //Uso el split "-" para separar de otro campo que tengo            

         } 
?>
```

Ahora mismo en la tabla me asigna el mismo precio `$total`.

Comment: De entrada, estás asociando un id fijo dentro de un bucle: `total_precio_peso`, lo cual no es correcto. Los IDs deben ser únicos. Deberías considerar organizar mejor tu código, por ejemplo, en vez de un `id` puedes poner otro tipo de selector a los elementos que sí pueda repetirse (una clase por ejemplo) y luego seleccionar todos los `<span>` de esa clase y actualizarlos.

Comment: Tienes razón. Gracias. He probado asignando una clase y efectivamente muestra en todos los registros. El problema es que me devuelve el mismo resultado en todos los registros.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que *me devuelve el mismo resultado en todos los registros*, a los datos de la consulta o a que se coloca el mismo resultado en todos los registros? Pulsa en [edit] para actualizar el código a como lo tienes ahora. Y explica un poco el contexto... supongo que quieres ir actualizando cada valor según cada fila de la consulta SQL. Aunque me pregunto por qué no haces todo en el servidor ¿? Este no parece ser un contexto dinámico, o al menos eso no aparece en las explicaciones que das.

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, a ver si está mejor explicado.